# не работает стандартное приложение при запуске на эмуляторе

Tags: android, flutter

Вот такая ошибка при за пуске приложения:

командная говорит что все окей что делать?

[image]

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
       primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Текстовую информацию добавьте текстом вместо скриншотов.

Comment: ну почему не работает, у вас обычный timeout и все, смотрите есть ли доступ к запрашиваемому ресурсу, через постман например.

Comment: и приложите код все-таки, а то по ошибке гадать как-то не гуд

Comment: чисто гипотетически проблемы могут быть в эмуляторе который вы используете, вы пробовали запускать в браузере например? это же кроссплатформа, попробуйте пнуть через браузер

Comment: в браузере запускается

Comment: Судя по ошибке, у вас падает Gradle-сборка  проекта на шаге `assembleDebug`. Попробуйте добавить опции [`--info`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_logging) и [`--stacktrace`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_debugging) при запуске [`gradle`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html), тогда вы получите больше подробностей об ошибке.